# Referring to tooltip within event listener to keep it open on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

Finding myself in a bit of a strange position where I have to reference the tooltip within an instantiation for all tooltips.

```
$('body').tooltip({
    selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]',
    html: true,
    animation: false,
}).on("mouseenter", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var _this = e.target;
    $(_this).tooltip("show");
    $(".tooltip").on("mouseleave", function () {
        $(_this).tooltip('hide');
    });
}).on("mouseleave", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var _this = e.target;
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (!$(".tooltip:hover").length) {
            $(_this).tooltip("hide");
        }
    }, 300);
});
```

That being said, how can I:

- Reference the actual element that is triggering this jQuery call
- Keep the tooltip open while either the actual tooltip or element that generated it are being hovered over?

Here is a link to a JSFiddle prototype:
https://jsfiddle.net/cwv57weu/8/

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Answer (score 2):

Use `event.target`.

```
$('body').tooltip({
    selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]',
    html: true,
    animation: false,
}).on("mouseenter", function (e) {
    var _this = e.target;
    $(_this).tooltip("show");
    $(".tooltip").one("mouseleave", function () {
        $(_this).tooltip('hide');
    });
}).on("mouseleave", function (e) {
    var _this = e.target;
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (!$(".tooltip:hover").length) {
            $(_this).tooltip("hide");
        }
    }, 300);
});
```

`e.target` is the actual element that the event originated on, while `this` is the element that the event listener was attached to (equivalent to `e.currentTarget`).

Note that because of event bubbling, the event will fire on all the containing elements up to `body`. You may want to use `e.stopPropagation()` to prevent bubbling, so you only process the deepest element.

I also changed the `mouseleave` handler on `.tooltip` to use `.one()`. Otherwise, every time you enter something, you'll add another `mouseleave` handler to all the tooltips, without removing the previous one, and soon there will be thousands of handlers running (this is why it's generally wrong to bind event handlers inside other event handlers). I'm not really sure you need both that `mouseleave` handler and the one you attach to `body`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Updated my methods to your recommendations. I included the the e.stopPropagation method, which is a good idea. However, for some reason the tooltip still refuses to stay open. Any ideas on why this may be?

Comment: I just made some changes, but I'm not sure if they'll help with the problem. Can you make an executable Stack Snippet that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Hmm that still seems to leave it hanging. Updated with a JSFiddle

Comment: I can't quite pin it down, but the tooltip is disappearing even when neither of the `.tooltip("hide")` methods are being called from your code. I added `console.log` after them, and they usually don't appear. So I think Bootstrap is removing the tooltip automatically.

Comment: any other way to reference $(".tooltip").on() from that scope?

Answer (score 2):

Within your '.on()' call, you can add an 'event' argument to your anonymous function. This will contain all of the data from the event including the element which triggered the event (it will be referenced as 'target').

```
}).on("mouseenter", function (event) {
    $(event.target).tooltip("show");
})
```

the event argument contains a ton of data, I would play around with it by console.log(event) within your anonymous function to get a feel as to what data is available to you.